# Beginner..can't figure out what is wrong with my add on Arraylist

Tags: java

It keeps saying `no suitable method found for add`.

```
public class MovieLibrary {

    private ArrayList<Movie> movies; 

    public MovieLibrary() {
        movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    }

    public void addMovie(String title, int year) {
        movies.add(title);
        movies.add(year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can only add objects of type `Movie` in your `ArrayList`. So first make an object out of title and year and then add it to your `ArrayList`. So based on how your `Movie` class is designed it might look something like this:

```
       public void addMovie(String title, int year)
       {
         Movie movie = new Movie(title, year);
         movies.add(movie);
       }
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

movies is an `ArrayList` of `Movie` while you are trying to add `String` and `int`. You can't mix different type in an `ArrayList` that is explicity typed unless are different objects that are in an inheritance hierarchy (like subclasses).

You should do something like this if you have a `Movie(String title, int year)` constructor:

```
public void addMovie(String title, int year){
    Movie m = new Movie(title, year)
    movies.add(m);
}
```

If not, create a `new Movie()` and then use getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add String(s) into a list that you have created to accept objects of type Movies